# Coloring 1 bar on a chart based off of a formula

Tags: excel, vba, charts, colors, formatting

I am building a simple chart that shows our companies gross profit in comparison to a budget. I am curious if there is a way to change our "actual gross profit" bar's color to green if the gross profit is higher than budget, or red if it is lower than budget. I am using excel 2013.

Comment: Anything Excel chart related you should refer to Jon Peltier's site. In this case, he explains it in [Conditional Formatting of Excel Charts](http://peltiertech.com/conditional-formatting-of-excel-charts/).

Answer (score 0):

I did some more research and found another workaround for my own question. There is a way to change a picture based off of a formula using indirect. i made 2 copies of my chart and put them on a different worksheet in my workbook, then altered one chart to have the first bar green and in the second chart made that bar red. then using the indirect formula i found i was able to change the source image into chart A if a cell met a set criteria or chart B if it did not.